# Is there a std::streambuf version that converts host to network byte order?

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio, endianness

Is there a `std::streambuf`-like mechanism to convert multi-byte values to network-byte order?    In particular, does Boost Asio offer such a primitive? Here is an example of what I would like the stream buffer to do:

```
uint64_t x = 42ull;
network_streambuf b1;
std::ostream os(&b1);
os << 42ull; // htonll

network_streambuf b2;
std::istream is(&b2);
uint64_t y;
is >> y; // ntohll
```

**EDIT**: The answers suggest that this is the wrong way to think about the problem: stream buffers simply provide access to character sequences, their job is not to perform formatted I/O or conversion. I will probably implement a small buffer class that provides the necessary overloads for `operator<<` and `operator>>` to perform the conversion.

Comment: Your question would make more sense if you defined `b2` in your example. Also, why would `operator<<(…, unsigned long long)` invoke `htons`? Wouldn't you prefer it to invoke `htonll`?

Comment: Thanks Rob, I corrected the bugs.

Comment: I think you're looking for the solution in the wrong place. By the time the formatter (`ostream`) has finished it is passing a stream of bytes to the `streambuf`. It sounds like you actually want a "binary" `ostream` if byte order of the output numbers is an issue that you a are trying to solve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, and I'll tell you why.

`istream::operator>>` and `ostream::operator<<` operate on a stream of characters, converting them from their human-readable form to the computer's native form. `streambuf` doesn't participate in that conversion at all, except to provide (or accept) a stream of characters.

To put it another way, the formatted I/O routines convert from character form to binary form.

You are asking for a conversion from one binary form to another binary form. That isn't the same thing, and the `stream` formatted text routines are the wrong place to look.

That said, you *could* create your own class that implements `operator<<` and `operator>>`, and have *those* routines do network byte swapping.

Comment: yet this is a common pattern, especially in networking. is there library offering a similar service?